# What is the best way to implement business logic & aggregation in an SQL database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, aggregation, business-logic

Currently I am doing the aggregation & business logic (joins, revenue calculation, ect) partly in an SQL database and I am wondering if there is a general best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

With this little information available, it is hard to give you proper advice, but as a general rule of thumb, the more business logic you can implement in the database layer, the better. SQL Server is good for set-based calculations and aggregations, and that's typically what business logic would be based on.

Another advantage is that by implementing the logic in the database, your data/business logic definitions are conformed, and can be based on the business signing off on the definitions. If you'd leave that part out, when 2 different analysts will attempt to create the same business logic in Power BI, they might end up with slightly different implementations that could lead to different results. By implementing it in the back-end, both analysts would get the same output, no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @SchmitzIT :) 
Then how would you implement complex aggregation in SQL? Would you use views or something else?

Comment: @KevinConseil - It depends on your needs. My main job involves data warehousing, where complex aggregations are a standard practice. We typically persist the calculations, because that way you only have to do the aggregation once (as opposed to performing them every time on the fly when someone executes a view). However, that might not always be feasible (rolling averages, or up-to-date current inventory numbers in a real-time scenario), for instance. So it depends on your business needs, data volume, etc.

Comment: what do you mean by persist the calculations? I implemented rolling average and cumulative calculations using a view and the performance is terrible. I would really appreciate to know what are the other possibilities :)

Comment: @KevinConseil - By persisting, I mean we store the results of the calculations in the database. For cumulative calculations, this works very well (You add the previous cumulative value and whatever new value you have). The advantage is that the calculation happens only once, and you can always check the database what the value was at a specific point in time. For rolling averages, it might be a bit more tricky, due to the nature of such calculations, but in such cases, you would typically keep the transnational history somewhere so you can repeat the calculation after adding the new data.

Comment: ok and which tool or method do you use to store the results of the calculation? I am using a workflow tool for my ETL, so typically in my case you would use such tool to do the calculation once and then implement it in a fix table. am i right?

Comment: Traditionally we would use SSIS (Nowadays Azure Data Factory). We grab data from our extract layer, and then transform it to a Stage Layer. The transform logic would be in a stored procedure and is where we handle business logic, JOINs, etc. It's also where I'd add calculations. The result of the calculation simply is part of the INSERT into the Stage Table (so that table contains a column per calculation).

Comment: @SchnitzIT: alright so if i summarized: 

1- grab data 

2- Transformation of the data including JOINs, busienss logics, ect into a staging table 

3- data insert to ops table


Am I right?

Comment: @KevinConseil Correct. That's how we typically do our ETL logic. So step 3 will be to move the data from Stage to dim or fact. We typically do not do any further transformations in there (other than replacing NULL values in dimension Keys with a "Dummy" value), and implementing a Surrogate Key.

Comment: @SchnitzIT: alright got it. In staging there is just the new fresh data and then you incrementally move those data to the dim or fact table?

Comment: @KevinConseil - That would depend on whether you are doing full loads or delta loads. For delta, yes, only the recent data would be moved. In the case of full loads, of course everything is moved.

Comment: @SchnitzIT: Thanks for your advices. 
One remaining question: How would you implement changes or new metrics on your historical data (the final fact table)?

I think I m gonna proceed as follow:
1- data load into staging temporary tables with limited historical data (last 6 weeks)
2- view on top of those tables in order to aggregate, join and build metrics
3- load the data from the view into fact tables that gonna store all my historical data

Any comments on this?

Comment: @KevinConseil - It depends. Ideally, you would have your historic data available. Perhaps in an extractHistory schema. If that is the case, you simply use that for reloading your fact table. If that is not an option, I'd probably create a new fact table, using the old one as a source, and when done reloading, swap the two tables (I.e. Fact.Transactions feeds fact.Transactions_New. When done, rename fact.Transactions to fact.Transactions_old, and fact.Transactions_New to fact.Transactions).